# `sam build` suddenly fails with `pip executable not found in your python environment` on Mac

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm building an aws lambda function, written in Python3.10, with `sam build`.

After some changes (code changes, files added, modules added) - nothing fancy, my build suddenly stops working. I get the error message  `Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - pip executable not found in your python environment`.

The files I changed

```
modified:   projectroot/aa/bb.py
deleted:    projectroot/cc/dd.py
modified:   projectroot/ee/ff.py
added:      projectroot/types/__init__.py
```

*What I've tried*

- I checked if pip was there. It is: in the virtual env, as well as the system.
- I tried re-initializing the venv.
- I tried rebooting (expecting it to one of Mac's hickups)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a folder **types** was the problem:

```
added:      projectroot/types/__init__.py
```

#### Assumed Reason (not verified):

The way aws packs lambda functions somehow causes the python-internal types folder to be overwritten, which in turn causes that error.

#### Future-proof solution

I'd suggest putting all your files and folders into a separated folder below *projectroot*.

E.g.

```
projectroot/main.py
projectroot/myproject/*
```